# Is it possible to implement IAP in iOS build of LIBGDX?

Tags: ios, libgdx, robovm

I am trying to use IAP in the iOS build of LIBGDX. It's a green light from the Android side but from iOS I am not even sure if it's feasible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are still wondering . yes it's possible . 
Download IOS Inapp Bindings from here [Robovm Bindings](https://github.com/BlueRiverInteractive/robovm-ios-bindings/issues) and look for sample class.

cheers